# Kotlin Object Supertype Constructor

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I need to implement a singleton `MyClass` in kotlin.

Requirements:

1. MyClass has the supertype `SuperClass` and I need to call the constructor of `Superclass`
2. I need to pass a context to `MyClass` and need the context to call the constructor of `Superclass`.
3. `MyClass` is a singleton.

Java equivalent:

```
class MyClass extends SuperClass
{
    // instance variable
    // getInstance() method
    MyClass(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }
}
```

I tried to solve this with an `object` but didn't get it working.

Is there a way to get it working with an object or do I have to use a `companion object`?

Comment: If you know how to implement what you want in Java but not in Kotlin, two things: 1) you should/can have that bit implemented in Java and interact with it from Kotlin, and 2) IntelliJ IDEA offers to auto-convert Java into Kotlin inside the IDE.

Comment: @Whymarrh 1) I know but I wanted to ask to learn a bit more about kotlin (if someone has a better solution). 2) good idea, didn't remember.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following super class:

```
open class MySuperClass(val context: Context) {...}
```

Since Kotlin objects only have an empty constructor, you'd need a structure similar to the following:

```
// Private constructor is only accessible within the class.
class MySingleton private constructor(context: Context) : MySuperClass(context) {
    companion object {
        lateinit var INSTANCE: MySingleton
            // Instance setter is only accessible from within the class.
            private set

        // Custom init function is called from outside and replaces
        // THE WHOLE SINGLETON with a new instance
        // to avoid internal dependencies on the old context.
        fun init(context: Context) {
            INSTANCE = MySingleton(context.applicationContext)
        }
    }

    // Lazily initialized field dependent on a Context instance.
    val prefs by lazy { PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context) }
}
```

You need to call `init(context)` once before using your singleton class and the `Application` is a great place to do that. This will also create a new instance of your singleton each time Instant Run loads a new `Application` object so you always end up with the most up-to-date application context.

```
class MyApplication : Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        // Eagerly initialized singleton.
        MySingleton.init(this)
    }
}
```

Notes:

- Kotlin objects only have an empty constructor. If you need to initialize the object use a custom init function.
- If your fields depend on a context which may change it's better to use `class` instead of `object` and manage current instance yourself. You also have to do this if you need to pass parameters to super class of your singleton.
- Because you *eagerly* initialize the class at the start of your application (not at the first call of `getInstance(context)` it's a great idea to *lazily* the heavy objects within your singleton object.
- If your app is multi-process find a way to initialize your singleton only in the process you actually use it. (Hint: ContentProvider is created only in main process by default.)

Comment: But I still have the problem, that I cannot call the supertype's constructor.

Comment: Imagine this was possible. Imagine there was some code in your program that referred to `MyClass`. The `object` access syntax doesn't allow you to specify any parameters; you simply refer to the object by its class name. Where would the `context` instance come from?

Comment: @lampenlampen Remade the answer to suit your use case.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any objects or companion objects to achieve this. This is the syntax for calling the constructor of a superclass in Kotlin:

```
class MyClass(context: Context) : SuperClass(context)
```

Comment: Yeah, but I want the class to be a singleton. Added as third condition

Comment: To create a singleton in Kotlin, add `object` instead of `class`, eg replace `class MyObject` with `object MyClass`. That's it!